# Use htaccess for a redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am using the following code to change all my pages from .php to a simple /

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Now come up as www.site.com/clubs/ or www.site.com/training/ instead of www.site.com/clubs.php and www.site.com/training.php

Now within clubs i want to show the clubs (using data from a database) and the page will show as www.site.com/clubs/my-club/
All the my-club data will be in the database including the link in a url field.

I can get this with the following code. However when i echo using the $_GET['club'] method it is showing up my-club.php instead of just my-club.

```
RewriteRule ^clubs/([^/]*)$ clubs.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The ending / in the url seems to get changed into .php

Comment: How are rewrite rules sorted? I guess it depends on that

Comment: The one to change files from file.php to file/ is first then the clubs one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you need in different ways, however that's how I would do it.
Change rules order, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^clubs/([^/]*)/$ clubs.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

I added the trailing slash to the first rule, since I guess is part of the pattern. If I'm wrong about it you can just delete it.

If you want to append any query string from the original request URL you should use `QSA` together with `L`, so `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Ive read about that query string, but i never understood it. How would this differ from using [L]?

Comment: The difference is that using `QSA` a URL like `www.site.com/clubs/my-club/?k1=v1&k2=v2` would be rewritten as `clubs.php?url=my-club&k1=v1&k2=v2`; without QSA the query string would be ignored. Of course it all depends on what you need.

Comment: So im may case it would be if i was passing parameters through my-club page then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?$ $1.php?url=$2
```

Whan are you run:

```
http://localhost/club/
```

result will be

```
http://localhost/club.php
```

Whan are you run:

```
http://localhost/club/my-club
```

result will be

```
http://localhost/club.php?url=my-club
```